# Difference between iterative methods (Gauss-Seidel, Newton-like methods) and Runge-Kutta methods for ODE / PDE solutions

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, runge-kutta-methods

This is a general question to try and understand conceptually (in laymans (i.e. engineers) terms) the differences between the above solution methods for things like solving ODEs and PDEs. For context, I have done work in the CFD industry, and so am familiar with discretization schemes for FV-based CFD and FEM, and so am comfortable with how in most discretization methods, we end up with linear systems like $Ax=b$ which we need to solve (with things iterative solvers, Gauss-Seidel, conjugate gradient methods etc) but can't seem to understand how the Runge-Kutta methods fit into the mix.

For context, I am not looking for an indepth explanation of each kind of RK method as I can read this up myself, but more conceptually how they differ from the `normal' solution methods for systems of linear equations. Hopefully thats not too broad a question.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You should be aware that the linear solvers handle the connections in space directions, and the Runge-Kutta and multi-step methods in time direction? So there is no difference here, your usual methods amount to something like or similar to Euler or trapezium methods. Higher order in time direction is less important than higher stability, the FV space discretization afaik is not very smooth so that higher order methods do not deliver the advertised performance.

Comment: Thanks! So Runge-Kutta is for the treatment of the temporal derivatives only?

Comment: Yes. Clearest if you have organized the space discretization compatible with the method-of-lines, meaning you have a finite difference or finite element discretization of space. With finite volume this is not so clear-cut, as, as far as I have seen, the propagation is not time-reversible (disregarding stability issues, MoL is reversible).